# Custom query filter in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Here is my models code:

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    """Quote model."""
    quote_text = models.TextField(unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    hit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want filter all Quote based on characters length, and this is my query in django admin.

```
class QuoteCountFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    """Filter based on quote_text characters count."""
    title = _('Quote Text Char Count')
    parameter_name = 'quotelength'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('lessthan50', _('Less than 50')),
            ('morethan50', _('More than 50')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'lessthan50':
            return queryset.extra(select={"val": "SELECT id FROM web_quote WHERE character_length(quote_text) < 50"})
```

However, it returns **Programming error more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

Any ideas how to fix?

What I am trying is to find all `Quote`s where `quote_text` length is less than 50 characters

Comment: [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) It would deprecate in near future. You should be very careful whenever you use extra(). Every time you use it, you should escape any parameters that the user can control by using params in order to protect against SQL injection attacks

Comment: @e4c5 I already add my models in my questions, I want to find all Quote which quote_text length less than 50 characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say goodbye to `extra` and say hello to [Length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Length)

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length

queryset.annotate(len=Length('quote_text').filter(len__lt=50)
```

much neater, safer and shorter

Comment: Glad to you like it :-) all the best with your project

Comment: @e4c5 Good one!